# How to deduce left-hand side matrix from vector?

Tags: octave, matrix-multiplication, symbolic-math

Suppose I have the following script, which constructs a symbolic array, `A_known`, and a symbolic vector `x`, and performs a matrix multiplication.

```
clc; clearvars
try
    pkg load symbolic
catch
    error('Symbolic package not available!');
end

syms V_l k s0 s_mean
N = 3;

% Generate left-hand-side square matrix
A_known = sym(zeros(N));
for hI = 1:N
    A_known(hI, 1:hI) = exp(-(hI:-1:1)*k);
end
A_known = A_known./V_l;

% Generate x vector
x = sym('x', [N 1]);
x(1) = x(1) + s0*V_l;
% Matrix multiplication to give b vector
b = A_known*x
```

Suppose `A_known` was actually *unknown*. Is there a way to deduce it from `b` and `x`? If so, how?

Til now, I only had the case where `x` was unknown, which normally [can be solved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Matrix_solution) via `x = b \ A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, it is possible to get a solution, but it actually has *infinite solutions*.

**Example**

```
A = magic(5);
x = (1:5)';
b = A*x;
A_sol = b*pinv(x);
```

which has

```
>> A
A =

   17   24    1    8   15
   23    5    7   14   16
    4    6   13   20   22
   10   12   19   21    3
   11   18   25    2    9
```

but solves `A` as `A_sol` like

```
>> A_sol
A_sol =

    3.1818    6.3636    9.5455   12.7273   15.9091
    3.4545    6.9091   10.3636   13.8182   17.2727
    4.4545    8.9091   13.3636   17.8182   22.2727
    3.4545    6.9091   10.3636   13.8182   17.2727
    3.1818    6.3636    9.5455   12.7273   15.9091
```

Comment: It also works for my symbolic case. Of course, `A_unknown` is not equal to `A_known`. Even if the upper triangle of `A` is 0, there is still six nonzeros terms, but only three equations to determine them, so the system is under-determined.